# How to display a tooltip in Jquery with custom div elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, scss-mixins

I am designing a nav bar using jQuery and I want to display a tooltip with custom div elements on hover of the menu items. All these are dynamic and part of an api response.

Here is my code-
main.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  fetch('https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/6766327f-607d-11e9-95ef-9bcb815ba4a4', {mode: 'cors'})
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(returnedValue) {
      console.log('Request successful', returnedValue);
      var menuListEmpty = '';
      $.each(returnedValue, function (index) {
        console.log(index);
        var subMenuListItems = '';
        $.each(returnedValue[index], function(key, value){
            subMenuListItems += '<div><h3 class="linkTitle">'+value.title+'</h3><p class="linkSub">'+value['sub-title']+'</p></div>'

        })
        var tooltipWrapper = '<div id="my-tip" class="tip-content hidden">'+subMenuListItems+'</div>'
        menuListEmpty += '<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link tip" data-tip="my-tip"href="#">'+ index +'</a>'+tooltipWrapper+'</li>'  
         // Tooltips
         $('.tip').each(function () {
          $(this).tooltip({
              html: true,
              title: $('.' + $(this).data('tip')).html()
          });
        }); 
      })
     $('.customNav').append($( '<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg"><ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">' +menuListEmpty+ '</ul></nav>'));
     })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log('Request failed', error)
   });
});
```

My html file-

```
<body>
   <div class="container-lg">
    <header class="customNav"></header>
   </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
```

My scss-

```
.customNav {
  font-family: Camphor,Open Sans,Segoe UI,sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;

    .linkTitle {
      margin: 0;
      color: #6772e5;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 22px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: 600;
      letter-spacing: .025em;
    }

    .linkSub {
      font-size: 15px;
      line-height: 22px;
      color: #6b7c93;
      margin: 5px 0 0;
      display: block;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .tip {
      text-transform: capitalize;
    }
}

div.tip-content.hidden {
  display:none;
  transform: translateX(406px);
  height: 643px;
  width: 494px;
}
a.nav-link.tip:hover+div.tip-content.hidden {
  display:block;
}
```

It's getting rendered correctly but the only problem is tooltip div is shown on page load as well.It should be hidden initially and should be displayed only on menu list hover. Can someone help me understand where I am going wrong? Help much appreciated.

Comment: You can use the `.hover()` function with the css `display: none` rule to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use css here for hiding your lists.

```
div.tip-content.hidden {
  display:none;
}
a.nav-link.tip:hover+div.tip-content.hidden {
  display:block;
}
```

And don't use id="my-tip" for all of your blocks. Id must be unique on the page.

Comment: This does handle hide and show of the tooltipWrapper, however, it doesn't appear like tooltip i.e with a pointed arrow. Am I missing something in code?

Comment: Yes, you can. About arrow... Show your css.

Comment: Have added the css, Please have a look.

Comment: I don't see any styles for arrow here. Why should it be displayed and where ?

Comment: I haven't added it yet. I want the css to give the look of a tooltip once I hover on my menu items.

Answer (score 1):

I'd hide the .tip css using:

```
display: none;
```

Then I would use jQuery .hover() to show and hide the tips:

https://api.jquery.com/hover/